# Apply some field description using an XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-serialization

I need a verry especific format for each field of `MyObject` class

```
public class MyObject{
  public Long Amount {get; set}
  public Long FiscalAmount {get; set;}
  // .... A lot more of fields
}
```

For example,

- if `MyObject.Amount` is 5000 the expected result is 00005000.
- if `MyObject.FiscalAmount` is 23 the expected result is 000023

In order to accomplished this, I have defined an XML file:

```
<FieldDescriptionXML>
    <FielDefinition>
     <Name>Amount</Name>
     <FillWith>0</FillWith>
     <Lenght>8</Lenght>
    </FielDefinition>
    <FielDefinition>
     <Name>FiscalAmount</Name>
     <FillWith>0</FillWith>
     <Lenght>6</Lenght>
    </FielDefinition>
    .... A lot more of fields
<FieldDescriptionXML>
```

Then I use the following code to get `MyObject` fields with the desired output

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.Amount = 5000;
...
// Gets the xml definition
// I deserialize the previous XML file and name it FieldDescription
List<FieldDescription> fieldDescriptionList = DeserializeXML(XMLFilePath);

FieldDescription fieldDescription = fieldDescriptionList.Find(x => x.Name == "Amount");

// Apply the field definition and returns a string.
// For this I use a private method called ApplyXMLFielDefinition 
// where I got how many spaces the result should be filled
string result = ApplyXMLFielDefinition(myObject.Amount,fieldDescription);
Console.Writeline(result) // prints 00005000 
// Now same code for MyObject.FiscalAmount
```

As you see, I got the desired output, but I had to do it one by one repeating the code.

Is there any other other better approached you can share?, thanks.

Environment: C# 4.0

Comment: What is `FieldDescription`? What is `ApplyXMLFielDefinition`?

Comment: `FieldDescription` is the serialized xml file. In `ApplyXMLFielDefinition`, I used the `FieldDescription` values to give the `myObject.Amount` the desired format. In this case, what is does is filled the value 5000 with four zeros.

Comment: Show the methods, not description what they do... And *serialized xml file* means nothing. It should probably be *deserialized*, and important part is: deserialized to what?

Comment: FieldDescription is a List<T> ? means list of class

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly you will have a list of elements you want populated from a large xml collection. Have you tried [LinqToXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

```
var x = (from target in xmlDoc.Decendants("FielDefinition")
        select (int) target.Element("FillWith").value()
         where target.Element("Name").Value.tolower() == "amount")).ToList();
```

That will return a `list<int>`